# Bison matching wrong tokens

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

While having a problem with PLY, I tried rephrasing the same grammar fragment in bison and encountered a similar problem. This suggests I might be doing something wrong.

A symbolic representation of the grammar fragment looks like this:

```
document -> fragment?
fragment -> { \n line* \n fragment? }
line     -> [^\n]+ \n
```

The relevant lex lines:

```
[{}]   return *yytext;
[^\n]+ return ANYTHING;
\n     return EOL;
```

The relevant bison lines:

```
multiline: '{' EOL lines EOL multiline '}'
         |
         ;

lines: lines ANYTHING EOL
     |
     ;
```

The grammar is deterministic, for all I know should even be LALR(1) (haven't really tried to build the tableau, though). A document like `"{\n\n}"` parses OK, but a document where the `multiline` elements are nested (e.g. `"{\n\n{\n\n}}"`) does not, the lexer sees the last `"}}"` as a token `"ANYTHING"` rather than two `'}'`s.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `[^{}\n]+ return ANYTHING;` ?

Comment: That one works, but the original thought behind separating the text into "lines" was to allow any non-EOL character into the fields.

Comment: Well that would eat all your `{}` , wouldn't it? Lex is greedy: if two patterns match the current input, the longest match wins.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't bison instruct lex about what tokens are allowed during non-error mode? Also lex doesn't eat all `{}`, just the ones at the end. (which would be consistent with the lex greed...)

Comment: @wildplasser Could you post your comment as an answer so that it can be upvoted? :-)

Comment: @mistotebe, as wildplasser mentioned: the longest match "wins". And no, bison doesn't instruct lex anything: it simply asks a token from lex which lex provides regardless of what bison is trying to match.

Answer (score 3):

```
[{}]   return *yytext;
[^{}\n]+ return ANYTHING;
\n     return EOL;
```

Lex is greedy: if two patterns match the current input, the longest match wins. In the original lex fragment, the `[^\n]+` pattern catches lines with `{` or `}` in them.

Comment: Yes that is one solution, restricting `ANYTHING` not to clash with *any* other lexeme (yuck!) and add a nonterminal rule ANYTHING_ that assembles all of them there... Isn't there a possibility to set the lexer states reliably enough to have a single `ANYTHING` lexeme that only triggers in the right places?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you want ANYTHING to match anything except \n and {}, then the negated character class is the way to go (what is wrong with it?). If you want {} to be preserved (eg in strings or comments) then you'll probably need start conditions. (or create the lexer manually, since it appears simple enough)

Comment: It's just a fragment of [this](http://mistotebe.net/image/grammar.txt), there are other lexemes and the way to specify the ANYTHING token will get quite tedious. What are those start conditions?

Comment: Start conditions can be used if there are multiple sets of lexemes, depending on the "subsection" of the syntax. You might find more information on start conditions in the [f]lex manuals.